# Segmentation fault with elastic search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, rubygems, apple-m1

I'm receiving this error and none of the known fixes found works for me.
What I've tried

- removing patron gem to use ethon as default
- reinstalling MacOS Monterrey from scratch
- reinstalling curl

The issue is thrown whit every action related to elastic search

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]
```

Line that generates the issue:
`US::City.__elasticsearch__.create_index!`

```
/Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/patron-0.13.3/lib/patron/session.rb:330: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000110
ruby 2.7.5p203 (2021-11-24 revision f69aeb8314) [arm64-darwin21]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   for more details.
Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file in bug reports.

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0106 p:---- s:0621 e:000620 CFUNC  :handle_request
c:0105 p:0022 s:0616 e:000615 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/patron-0.13.3/lib/patron/session.rb:330
c:0104 p:0048 s:0607 e:000606 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/faraday-patron-1.0.0/lib/faraday/adapter/patron.rb:32
c:0103 p:0019 s:0602 e:000601 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/faraday-1.10.0/lib/faraday/adapter.rb:50
c:0102 p:0040 s:0596 e:000595 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/faraday-patron-1.0.0/lib/faraday/adapter/patron.rb:29
c:0101 p:0012 s:0587 e:000586 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/faraday-1.10.0/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:154
c:0100 p:0062 s:0581 e:000580 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/faraday-1.10.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:516
c:0099 p:0043 s:0572 e:000571 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-7.10.0/lib/elasticsearch/transport/t
c:0098 p:0259 s:0566 e:000565 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-7.10.0/lib/elasticsearch/transport/t
c:0097 p:0030 s:0543 e:000542 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-7.10.0/lib/elasticsearch/transport/t
c:0096 p:0112 s:0533 e:000532 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-7.10.0/lib/elasticsearch/transport/c
c:0095 p:0416 s:0523 e:000522 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/elasticsearch-api-7.10.0/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/index
c:0094 p:0051 s:0510 E:0005c8 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-7.1.1/lib/elasticsearch/model/indexing.r
c:0093 p:0005 s:0503 E:002670 METHOD /Users/lautarol/Documents/dev/work/biggerpockets/app/models/company_profile.rb:718 [FINISH]
c:0092 p:---- s:0499 e:000498 CFUNC  :each
c:0091 p:0017 s:0495 E:000610 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.6/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.r
c:0090 p:0022 s:0487 E:000638 METHOD /Users/lautarol/Documents/dev/work/biggerpockets/app/models/concerns/user/companies.rb:146
c:0089 p:0034 s:0482 E:000688 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:427
c:0088 p:0029 s:0474 E:0006c8 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:260
c:0087 p:0007 s:0468 E:000728 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:516 [FINISH]
c:0086 p:---- s:0464 e:000463 CFUNC  :each
c:0085 p:0006 s:0460 E:0006f8 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:516
c:0084 p:0099 s:0455 E:000778 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:107
c:0083 p:0009 s:0446 E:0007a8 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:824
c:0082 p:0016 s:0441 E:0007e0 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:321
c:0081 p:0091 s:0435 E:000828 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/a
c:0080 p:0028 s:0426 E:000858 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/a
c:0079 p:0003 s:0422 E:001060 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.6/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_in [FINISH]
c:0078 p:---- s:0419 e:000418 CFUNC  :handle_interrupt
c:0077 p:0026 s:0414 E:000a90 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.6/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_in [FINISH]
c:0076 p:---- s:0411 e:000410 CFUNC  :handle_interrupt
c:0075 p:0021 s:0406 E:002400 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.6/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_in
c:0074 p:0008 s:0402 E:001600 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/a
c:0073 p:0102 s:0398 E:001db0 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/a
c:0072 p:0003 s:0390 E:001e40 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.6/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_in [FINISH]
c:0071 p:---- s:0387 e:000386 CFUNC  :handle_interrupt
c:0070 p:0026 s:0382 E:001e20 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.6/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_in [FINISH]
c:0069 p:---- s:0379 e:000378 CFUNC  :handle_interrupt
c:0068 p:0021 s:0374 E:001e00 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.6/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_in
c:0067 p:0008 s:0370 E:001d68 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/a
c:0066 p:0050 s:0363 E:001ce0 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/a
c:0065 p:0023 s:0355 E:001c48 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:350
c:0064 p:0004 s:0348 E:001bb8 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:302
c:0063 p:0031 s:0343 E:001e68 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.6/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:48
c:0062 p:0312 s:0338 E:000418 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/Documents/dev/work/biggerpockets/db/seeds/topics.rb:47
c:0061 p:0043 s:0332 E:000478 METHOD /Users/lautarol/Documents/dev/work/biggerpockets/db/seed_support/time_stub.rb:27
c:0060 p:0025 s:0327 E:0003e0 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/Documents/dev/work/biggerpockets/db/seeds/topics.rb:22 [FINISH]
c:0059 p:---- s:0324 e:000323 CFUNC  :times
c:0058 p:0009 s:0320 E:001e98 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/Documents/dev/work/biggerpockets/db/seeds/topics.rb:21 [FINISH]
c:0057 p:---- s:0316 e:000315 CFUNC  :each
c:0056 p:0017 s:0312 E:001eb0 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.6/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.r
c:0055 p:0066 s:0304 E:000170 TOP    /Users/lautarol/Documents/dev/work/biggerpockets/db/seeds/topics.rb:20 [FINISH]
c:0054 p:---- s:0299 e:000298 CFUNC  :require
c:0053 p:0226 s:0294 E:000c60 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel
c:0052 p:0066 s:0284 E:000bf0 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35
c:0051 p:0047 s:0276 E:000ce8 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel
c:0050 p:0076 s:0269 E:002598 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/Documents/dev/work/biggerpockets/db/seeds.rb:111 [FINISH]
c:0049 p:---- s:0261 e:000260 CFUNC  :each
c:0048 p:0196 s:0257 E:0026b0 TOP    /Users/lautarol/Documents/dev/work/biggerpockets/db/seeds.rb:102 [FINISH]
c:0047 p:---- s:0252 e:000251 CFUNC  :load
c:0046 p:0037 s:0246 E:0026e8 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel
c:0045 p:0006 s:0239 E:000820 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:566
c:0044 p:0048 s:0236 E:000570 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117
c:0043 p:0015 s:0226 E:000008 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.6/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.r
c:0042 p:0010 s:0221 E:0005a0 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:640 [FINISH]
c:0041 p:---- s:0216 e:000215 CFUNC  :instance_exec
c:0040 p:0127 s:0210 E:0005f0 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126
c:0039 p:0124 s:0201 E:002458 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:137
c:0038 p:0023 s:0192 E:000ee8 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:566
c:0037 p:0010 s:0187 E:000db0 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.
c:0036 p:0030 s:0183 E:0000d0 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.ra
c:0035 p:0008 s:0180 E:000648 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281 [FINISH]
c:0034 p:---- s:0176 e:000175 CFUNC  :each
c:0033 p:0146 s:0172 E:000620 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281
c:0032 p:0042 s:0166 E:000678 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sentry-ruby-core-5.1.1/lib/sentry/rake.rb:26
c:0031 p:0141 s:0161 E:0006e8 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:219 [FINISH]
c:0030 p:---- s:0157 e:000156 CFUNC  :synchronize
c:0029 p:0026 s:0153 E:0006b8 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199
c:0028 p:0036 s:0146 E:000720 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:188
c:0027 p:0027 s:0140 E:000760 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:160
c:0026 p:0006 s:0132 E:000788 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116 [FINISH]
c:0025 p:---- s:0128 e:000127 CFUNC  :each
c:0024 p:0029 s:0124 E:002420 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116
c:0023 p:0019 s:0121 E:0007e8 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:125
c:0022 p:0004 s:0116 E:0025e0 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:110
c:0021 p:0016 s:0112 E:001be0 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:83
c:0020 p:0002 s:0109 E:001c38 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186
c:0019 p:0015 s:0104 E:001bb8 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:80
c:0018 p:0045 s:0099 E:001c68 TOP    /Users/lautarol/Documents/dev/work/biggerpockets/bin/rake:9 [FINISH]
c:0017 p:---- s:0095 e:000094 CFUNC  :load
c:0016 p:0037 s:0089 E:002048 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel
c:0015 p:0021 s:0082 E:0026f0 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:40
c:0014 p:0176 s:0078 E:001210 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:217
c:0013 p:0015 s:0075 E:001850 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.6/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:10 [FINISH]
c:0012 p:---- s:0072 e:000071 CFUNC  :fork
c:0011 p:0013 s:0068 E:002490 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.6/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:8
c:0010 p:0008 s:0062 E:000ee8 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.6/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:27
c:0009 p:0205 s:0057 E:0020c0 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:181
c:0008 p:0059 s:0043 E:0016b0 BLOCK  /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:144 [FINISH]
c:0007 p:---- s:0040 e:000039 CFUNC  :loop
c:0006 p:0016 s:0036 E:000690 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:138
c:0005 p:0168 s:0032 E:001d08 TOP    /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19 [FINISH]
c:0004 p:---- s:0028 e:000027 CFUNC  :require
c:0003 p:0195 s:0023 E:001798 METHOD /Users/lautarol/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85
c:0002 p:0005 s:0006 E:0011c0 EVAL   -e:1 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0003 E:0001d0 (none) [FINISH]
```

full log in https://gist.github.com/lautarol/816f1c10200b88315cae1716de2798f9

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue with your rails 6.1.4.6, I have a similar issue since updating from 6.1.4.1  -> 6.1.4.6 , ruby 3.0.3

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately dwngrading rails to 6.1.4.1 didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for me.
Ruby: 2.6.6

I even downgraded to ruby 2.6.0 and upgraded to ruby 2.7.0 but didn't work.
Finally, I increased the number of puma workers then the problem was solved.

```
# config/puma.rb
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 5)

# Run rails server
RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=true bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

[image]